# Django python csv. How to open and read a file

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm wondering how can I use python's library `csv` to open and read a file saved in a django `FileField`.

I tried opening the file outside of django with a script like this:

```
import csv
with open('the_csv_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

It prints the csv content correctly:

```
['EAN', 'NOMBRE', 'CANTIDAD', 'UNIDAD', 'SKU', 'PRECIO']
['7861024608794', 'Fioravanti', '1.35', 'L', '6546546', '666']
```

So, when I try to open the same file in django, it doesn't work:

```
stocklist.csv_file.open(mode="rb")
    csv_file = stocklist.csv_file.read()
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

It prints this:

```
['EAN']
['', '']
['NOMBRE']
['', '']
['CANTIDAD']
['', '']
['UNIDAD']
['', '']
['SKU']
['', '']
['PRECIO']
... etc
```

So, how do I use the `csv` library with a django csv file in a `FileField` ?

Comment: First of all I'd recommend using `unicodecsv` if you're using Python 2. And secondly, I'd really recommend setting `delimiter` and `quotechar` when saving or reading CSV files.

Comment: Added `delimiter` and `quotechar` but itstill doesn't work.